# Is repeating "is" here correct?

Tags: grammar

In [this](https://youtu.be/rCoFKUJ_8Yo?t=689) interview, Elon Musk was asked whether he thought there was an intelligent life somewhere in the universe and he started his answer saying:

> It seems probable, but I think this is one of the great questions in
>   physics and philosophy, **is**: "Where are the aliens?"

Why did he repeat "is" in his sentence?
Is there a grammatical rule that I miss?

Comment: It's just a "slip of the tongue." A few seconds earlier he paused and repeated himself, so he was probably just formulating his reply, and modifying it as he spoke.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you.

Comment: If I want to quote this sentence, should I leave it as is or substitute another word for "is"?

Comment: @Moha you may use *sic* (e.g. "[...] and philosophy, is(sic):[..]") to indicate that it is a probable mistake by the author and not a mistake in the quote. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sic#Conventional_use. You should not alter a quote, as you may miss some of its meaning and change its meaning.

Comment: @SJuan76 Thank you so much for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern you are questioning is so common that it has a couple of names, and has accumulated a lot of opinion.
 There is a short Wikipedia article devoted to it:
[Wikipedia "Double Copula"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_copula)

Here's a longer, less sympathetic, discussion :
[Grammarbook.com "the is-is hiccup"](https://data.grammarbook.com/blog/effective-writing/what-is-is-is-is-exasperating/)

Here's a more neutral, erudite discussion with other links:
[Yale.edu "Double is"](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/double-is)

Answer (score 1):

**The *double copula*, also known as the *reduplicative copula*,  *double is* :**

It is the usage of two successive copulae when only one is necessary, largely in spoken English. (Wikipedia).

Grammatically, it's not correct.

We sometimes make such mistakes in conversation; but it's ungrammatical and wrong in written English.

The comma and 'is' should be omitted to make it grammatically correct :

*It seems probable, but I think this is one of the great questions in physics and philosophy : "Where are the aliens?"*